Plotly graphs not showing in dbc.Container. 1 Error on the app with no content in it
I have a dbc.Container in an app showing various cards with basic data. But I want to replace them with Gauge Charts as the cards look clunky and i feel like the gauge charts would do a better job.
When I initially started, I wanted to add the gauge chart inside a dbc.Card item.
I got an initial idea from this SO link and added a sample card to see how it would look like. But it came up as shown in the screenshot below. 
Removing all the formatting, I tried the gauge chart and got the same situation. I also tried a simple plotly.express line chart and have the same output. Meanwhile a DCC or even a DBC table shows fine in the same place.
Below is the container for the overview page:
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from dash import html, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from datetime import datetime
from conversions import *
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def overview():
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///greenhouse.db", echo=False)
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        ghdata=pd.read_sql("""select *
                                from
                                    SENSOR_DATA
                                where
                                    MEASURE_DATE = (select
                                                        max(MEASURE_DATE)
                                                    from
                                                        SENSOR_DATA);""", conn)
        wadata=pd.read_sql("""select *
                                from
                                    WEATHER_API_DATA
                                where
                                    MEASURE_DATE = (select
                                                        max(MEASURE_DATE)
                                                    from
                                                        WEATHER_API_DATA);""", conn)
        unit = pd.read_sql("""select UNIT
                                from
                                    SETTING_DATA
                                where
                                    MEASURE_DATE = (select max(MEASURE_DATE) from SETTING_DATA);""", conn).values[0][0]
        units = pd.read_sql(f"""select * from UNITS where UNIT = '{unit}';""", conn).values[0]
    temp_unit = units[2]
    speed_unit = units[1]
    precip_unit = units[3]
    
    if unit == "SI":
        current_gh_temp = convert_to_fahrenheit(ghdata[['TEMPERATURE']].values[0][0])
        min_temp = convert_to_fahrenheit(ghdata[['MIN_TEMP']].values[0][0])
        max_temp = convert_to_fahrenheit(ghdata[['MAX_TEMP']].values[0][0])
        current_wa_temp = convert_to_fahrenheit(wadata[['CURRENT_TEMPERATURE']].values[0][0])
    else:
        current_gh_temp = ghdata[['TEMPERATURE']].values[0][0]
        min_temp = ghdata[['MIN_TEMP']].values[0][0]
        max_temp = ghdata[['MAX_TEMP']].values[0][0]
        current_wa_temp = wadata[['CURRENT_TEMPERATURE']].values[0][0]
    print(current_gh_temp)
    currenttime_card = dbc.Card([
                    dbc.CardHeader("Current Time"),
                    dbc.CardBody([html.H5(f"{datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)}")])
                    ],
                    outline=True,
        )
    lastmeasuredtime_card = dbc.Card([
                    dbc.CardHeader("Last Measured"),
                    dbc.CardBody([html.H5(f"{ghdata[['MEASURE_DATE']].values[0][0]}")])
                    ],
                    outline=True,
        )
    temp_card = dbc.Card([
                    dbc.CardHeader("Current Temperature"),
                    dbc.CardBody([
                        html.H5(f"{current_gh_temp} {temp_unit}"),
                        dbc.Button("History", color="primary")
                        ]
                     )
                ],
                    outline=True,
        )
    mintemp_card = dbc.Card([
                    dbc.CardHeader("Minimum"),
                    dbc.CardBody([
                        html.H5(f"{min_temp} {temp_unit}"),
                        ]
                     )
                ],
                    outline=True,
        )
    maxtemp_card = dbc.Card([
                    dbc.CardHeader("Maximum"),
                    dbc.CardBody([
                        html.H5(f"{max_temp} {temp_unit}"),
                        ]
                     )
                ],
                    outline=True,
        )
    
    card_grp1 = dbc.CardGroup([currenttime_card, lastmeasuredtime_card])
    card_grp2 = dbc.CardGroup([mintemp_card, temp_card, maxtemp_card])
        
#     temp_guage = html.Div(
#         dcc.Graph(figure=
#                 px.line(
#                     ghdata,
#                     x="MEASURE_DATE",
#                     y=["TEMPERATURE", "MIN_TEMP"]
#                     )
#                 )
#             )
    temp_guage = html.Div(
        dcc.Graph(figure=go.Figure
                  (
                    go.Indicator(
                        mode="gauge+number",
                        value=current_gh_temp,
                        domain={"x": [0,1], 'y':[0,1],},
                        title={"text": f"Temperature ({temp_unit})"}
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
#     temp_guage=dbc.Table.from_dataframe(ghdata[[]])
    return dbc.Container(
        dbc.Col(
            [
                html.Br(),
                dbc.Row(
                    [
                        dbc.Col(
                            [
                                card_grp1,
                            ]
                        )
                    ],
                    justify="center"
                ),
                html.Br(),
                dbc.Row(
                    [
                        dbc.Col(
                            [
                                dbc.Row(card_grp2),
#                                 dbc.Row(card_grp3), # Code removed to get minimal reproducable output
                            ]
                        ),
#                         dbc.Col(card_grp4) # Code removed to get minimal reproducable output
                    ],
                    justify="center"
                ),
                html.Br(),
                dbc.Row(
                    [
                        dbc.Col(
                            [
                                temp_guage
                            ]
                        )
                        ]
                    ),
                ]
            )
        )



The returned item is just called into a container on app.py
If anybody could shed light on what I am missing, I would greatly appreciate it.
Please also let me know if any additional data or information is needed to help answer my question.
Thanks in advance.
Edit:
Sample data as requested by Derek
unit:str = 'METRIC'
units:list = ['METRIC' 'KMPH' '°C' 'CM']
ghdata:pd.DataFrame = [
            {
                "MEASURE_DATE":"2024-07-25 13:40:00",
                "TEMPERATURE":25,"HUMIDITY":33,
                "PHOTORESISTOR_VOLTAGE":0.035,
                "MIN_TEMP":24,
                "MAX_TEMP":25,
                "MIN_HUM":33,
                "MAX_HUM":36,
                "DEVICE_NAME":"PICOW-2"
            }
        ]
wadata:pd.DataFrame = [
            {
                "LATITUDE":39.53,
                "LONGITUDE":-119.76,
                "TIMEZONE":"America\/Los_Angeles",
                "TIMEZONE_ABBR":"PDT",
                "MEASURE_DATE":"2024-08-02 14:00:00",
                "CURRENT_TEMPERATURE":37,
                "CURRENT_HUMIDITY":12,
                "CURRENT_PRECIPITATION":0,
                "CURRENT_WEATHER_CODE":"Overcast",
                "CURRENT_WIND_SPEED":1,
                "CURRENT_WIND_DIRECTION":34,
                "DAILY_WEATHER_CODE":"Overcast",
                "DAILY_TEMPERATURE_MAX":38,
                "DAILY_TEMPERATURE_MIN":18,
                "DAILY_WIND_SPEED_MAX":20,
                "SUNRISE_TIME":"2024-08-02 06:00:00",
                "SUNSET_TIME":"2024-08-02 20:10:00",
                "TEMPERATURE_UNIT":"\u00b0C",
                "HUMIDITY_UNIT":"%",
                "PRECIPITATION_UNIT":"mm",
                "WIND_SPEED_UNIT":"km\/h",
                "WIND_DIRECTION_UNIT":"\u00b0"
            }
        ]


it's a bit tough to debug your code without being able to access your data (which prevents us from running your code). is it possible you can provide sample dataframes for ghdata, wadata, unit, units ?

Updated sample data as requested.

As I was banging my head to the wall, figured, I would clone this on my work PC and it worked perfectly! After additional inspection, identified that some files & folders were missing from the plotly folder in my home PC! Reinstalled plotly using pip and I'm back in business. Mods may please close this question

As you suggested, I'm going to vote to close since I think it's pretty unlikely anyone else encounters this error. I'm glad you figured it out though!

As I was banging my head to the wall, figured, I would clone this on my work PC and it worked perfectly! After additional inspection, identified that some files & folders were missing from the plotly folder in my home PC! Reinstalled plotly using pip and I'm back in business.
Mods may please close this question. Thank you.
